# .htaccess: How do I redirect to a PHP script only when accessing a specific subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I created a .htaccess file that redirects .png QR code requests to a PHP QR code generator.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /qr/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.png
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ access-code.php?id=%1 [QSA,L]
```

It works well for the original intent, but also sends EVERY .png request to the same script. I need to alter the `RewriteCond` to only accept .png files if in the /qr/access-code/* directory.

I placed the .htaccess file in the following directory:

/qr/.htaccess

Example request that works well as intended (not an actual link):

http://mywebsite.com/qr/access-code/12345678.png

Example request that "works", but I don't want it to get redirected:

http://mywebsite.com/qr/img/background.png (not an actual link)

How can I adjust my .htaccess condition to make my rule function as intended?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /qr/
##If /document_root/dir/foo.png is an existent file##    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/access-code/$1 -f
##Rewrite /foo.png to access-code.php?id=foo.png
RewriteRule ^(.+\.png)$ access-code.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This is close I think, but not quite there. There are no files to be found in %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/access-code/$1. Those requests are to be redirected to access-code.php (which delivers a generated file). I'll continue to play with variations of this.

Comment: Update: Your last line is a good improvement over my original, better security, thanks! I made a tweak to your condition which seems to be working great. May I have you edit your answer and I'll give you the check? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/access-code/"`